# Default int value with xmlrpclib

Tags: python, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib

I tried to execute the following code, but `xmlrpclib` is raising an exception:

```
>>> import xmlrpclib
>>> data = """<?xml version="1.0"?> 
... <methodCall>
...     <methodName>test_method</methodName>
...     <params>
...         <param>
...             <value>
...                 <int/>
...             </value>
...         </param>
...     </params>
... </methodCall>"""
>>> xmlrpclib.loads(data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1141, in loads
    p.feed(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 558, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 829, in end
    return f(self, join(self._data, ""))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 864, in end_int
    self.append(int(data))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

If I replace `<int/>` by `<int></int>`, the error is the same; but with `<int>0</int>` no exception is raised. Same results in python3 with `xmlrpc.client`.

I tried to do the same thing with [PHP](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.xmlrpc.php), and it worked without any trouble:

```
php > $data = '<?xml version="1.0"?><methodCall><methodName>test_method</methodName><params><param><value><int/></value></param></params></methodCall>';
php > print_r(xmlrpc_decode($data));
Array
(
    [0] => 0
)
```

The [documentation](http://xml-rpc.net/faq/xmlrpcnetfaq-2-5-0.html) from the .NET implementation also implies that `<int/>` would be translated to 0:

> If an XML-RPC struct member is missing its corresponding .NET struct member will be set to null instead of the default value for the type if a non-nullable type had been used, for example null instead of zero for an integer.

Is this behaviour a bug from the Python implementation?

Comment: I guess so. Fill bug report.

Comment: @pacholik I'm asking the question because I've found not real specification about this very subject on the officiel website of XML-RPC. Maybe the PHP implementation just works because developers decided to add allow this case to their implementations despite the XML-RPC specifications?

Comment: I see. I'd still fill it anyway - if PHP and .NET supports it.

Answer (score 2):

Without passing judgement on Python implementation :) this monkey patch fixes the way end_int() handles empty data. In your example before calling xmlrpclib.loads(data):

```
class MyUnmarshaller(xmlrpclib.Unmarshaller):

    def end_int(self, data):
        self.append(int(data or "0"))
        self._value = 0
    dispatch = xmlrpclib.Unmarshaller.dispatch
    dispatch["i4"] = end_int
    dispatch["i8"] = end_int
    dispatch["int"] = end_int

xmlrpclib.Unmarshaller = MyUnmarshaller
```